# Is there a single or word or at least better phrase for "human powered vehicle"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

So that's bicycle, skateboard, scooter etc. Problem is that these also have motor powered versions, but if you just say vehicle, people will think that you mean cars or something. Also, you can't search for those powered versions collectively because what would you put in the search bar, "motor powered, human powered vehicles"? If you just use "powered vehicles" all results are cars.